# The 's' or 'es' word

Tags: plural-forms, possessives, morphology

Where do exactly put the 's' or 'es' word on the sentences? And why using that word on sentence? And when the right time to add the 's' or 'es' word?

Comment: [If a word ends with the letters **s, f, x, sh, ch,** or **z,** we must first add the letter **e** before adding the letter **s**.](http://www.actionfactor.com/pages/lesson-plans/v2.10-plurals.html) This rule applies regardless of whether we're conjugating a verb or pluralizing a noun, so it's *This problem sometimes **foxes** even clever **foxes***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Besides, of course, the host of exceptions to that rule ;)

Comment: @wavemode: I copied that text pretty unthinkingly, but now you're making me actually *look* at the list, I'm kinda wondering what **f** is doing in there. Off-hand I can't think of any exceptions for any of the other letters, but *all* the **f** words that come to mind *(briefs, cliffs, earmuffs,...)* seem to be exceptions. Perhaps it shouldn't be there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh FF! C'mon it's a sound rule not a spelling rule! (2 Stella  Artois, 2 lochs, 2 pince-nez. And the *F*? ... That ain't no sibilant ;)

Comment: @Araucaria: *That's* one of the reasons I should usually stick to posting comments rather than actual answers! As soon as I see yours, I'm inclined to think you're right. Language is essentially *spoken*, and regardless of spelling, the pluralizing suffixes are **-s, -z, -iz**, where the last one applies to singular nouns ending with a sibilant. So I don't know why the page I linked to included **f** at all - but as with *When do we use **an** rather than **a**?*, the answer is based on sound, not spelling. I think. But you probably *know*, so perhaps you should answer!

Answer (score 1):

The -s or -es is referred to as a morpheme, not a word, since it cannot stand alone. When -s or -es is added to a noun, it means that the noun phrase with that head refers to more than one individual.  "Persons in the kitchen" means that there is more than one person in the kitchen.  "Person in the kitchen" would refer to a single individual in the kitchen, but if there is more than one, -s is added to "person", since that the the head noun of the noun phrase "person in the kitchen".  "Head" refers to the most important word of a phrase.

Comment: But is the morpheme realised as  *s* and when as *es*?

Comment: @Araucaria, when it would be difficult to say -s, we use -es.

Comment: Yes, but that ain't no use to the poor old learners when it's down here in the comments! ;)